# PrimeFaces 5.0 datatable filter case sensitive

Tags: primefaces

In PrimeFaces 5.0, datatable filter is case sensitive. In Primefaces 4 the filter was not case sensitive. But now in 5.0 my app doesn't work.

Comment: edited grammar in comment somewhat. Can you provide an example of what once worked and now doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataTable Filtering v. 5.0.1
Filtering is case sensitive in 5.0, due to feedback it is now case insensitive. FilterEvent was also providing wrong information about the filters, it has been corrected as well.
http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3184

Comment: It is an Elite release and only available to PRO users and not community users though :)

Comment: Hi, @Tiny maybe you can help me with this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818578/java-rmi-marshalexception-could-not-load-class

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filterFunction option, like this:

In XHTML:

```
<p:column ... 
    filterBy="#{car.name}"
    filterFunction="#{carListView.filterByName}"
```

In View:

```
public boolean filterByName(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
    String filterText = (filter == null) ? null : filter.toString().trim();
    if (filterText == null || filterText.equals("")) {
        return true;
    }

    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    }

    String carName = value.toString().toUpperCase();
    filterText = filterText.toUpperCase();

    if (carName.contains(filterText)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This worked for me. Please refer to: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml (price column). And also page 153 at the PrimeFaces 5.0 manual (pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same problem. 
But I fix it replacing the filter class of primefaces.

1- create a package in you project: org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature

2 - create a class: FilterFeature

```
I've included this part on the class:
// FIX bug primefaces 5.0
// The filter should be case insensitive 
if(columnValue != null && filterValue!= null){
    columnValue = columnValue.toString().toUpperCase();
    filterValue = filterValue.toString().toUpperCase();
}
```

Copy the contents of this class to your file.

FilterFeature.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2009-2014 PrimeTek.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.MethodExpression;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;
import javax.faces.FacesException;
import org.primefaces.component.api.UIColumn;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer;
import javax.faces.component.ValueHolder;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.component.api.DynamicColumn;
import org.primefaces.component.column.Column;
import org.primefaces.component.columngroup.ColumnGroup;
import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable;
import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer;
import org.primefaces.component.row.Row;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.primefaces.model.filter.*;
import org.primefaces.util.Constants;

public class FilterFeature implements DataTableFeature {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DataTable.class.getName());

    private final static String STARTS_WITH_MATCH_MODE = "startsWith";
    private final static String ENDS_WITH_MATCH_MODE = "endsWith";
    private final static String CONTAINS_MATCH_MODE = "contains";
    private final static String EXACT_MATCH_MODE = "exact";
    private final static String LESS_THAN_MODE = "lt";
    private final static String LESS_THAN_EQUALS_MODE = "lte";
    private final static String GREATER_THAN_MODE = "gt";
    private final static String GREATER_THAN_EQUALS_MODE = "gte";
    private final static String EQUALS_MODE = "equals";
    private final static String IN_MODE = "in";
    private final static String GLOBAL_MODE = "global";

    final static Map<String,FilterConstraint> FILTER_CONSTRAINTS;

    static {
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS = new HashMap<String,FilterConstraint>();
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(STARTS_WITH_MATCH_MODE, new StartsWithFilterConstraint());
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(ENDS_WITH_MATCH_MODE, new EndsWithFilterConstraint());
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(CONTAINS_MATCH_MODE, new ContainsFilterConstraint());
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(EXACT_MATCH_MODE, new ExactFilterConstraint());
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(LESS_THAN_MODE, new LessThanFilterConstraint());
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(LESS_THAN_EQUALS_MODE, new LessThanEqualsFilterConstraint());
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(GREATER_THAN_MODE, new GreaterThanFilterConstraint());
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(GREATER_THAN_EQUALS_MODE, new GreaterThanEqualsFilterConstraint());
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(EQUALS_MODE, new EqualsFilterConstraint());
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(IN_MODE, new InFilterConstraint());
        FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.put(GLOBAL_MODE, new GlobalFilterConstraint());
    }

    private boolean isFilterRequest(FacesContext context, DataTable table) {
        return context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().containsKey(table.getClientId(context) + "_filtering");
    }

    public boolean shouldDecode(FacesContext context, DataTable table) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean shouldEncode(FacesContext context, DataTable table) {
        return isFilterRequest(context, table);
    }

    public void decode(FacesContext context, DataTable table) {
        String globalFilterParam = table.getClientId(context) + UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(context) + "globalFilter";
        List<FilterMeta> filterMetadata = this.populateFilterMetaData(context, table);
        Map<String,Object> filterParameterMap = this.populateFilterParameterMap(context, table, filterMetadata, globalFilterParam);
        table.setFilters(filterParameterMap);
        table.setFilterMetadata(filterMetadata);
    }

    public void encode(FacesContext context, DataTableRenderer renderer, DataTable table) throws IOException {
        //reset state
        updateFilteredValue(context, table, null);
        table.setFirst(0);
        table.setRowIndex(-1);

        if(table.isLazy()) {
            table.loadLazyData();
        }
        else {
            String globalFilterParam = table.getClientId(context) + UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(context) + "globalFilter";
            filter(context, table, table.getFilterMetadata(), globalFilterParam);

            //sort new filtered data to restore sort state
            boolean sorted = (table.getValueExpression("sortBy") != null || table.getSortBy() != null);
            if(sorted) {
                SortFeature sortFeature = (SortFeature) table.getFeature(DataTableFeatureKey.SORT);

                if(table.isMultiSort())
                    sortFeature.multiSort(context, table);
                else
                    sortFeature.singleSort(context, table);
            }
        }

        renderer.encodeTbody(context, table, true);
    }

    private void filter(FacesContext context, DataTable table, List<FilterMeta> filterMetadata, String globalFilterParam) {
        Map<String,String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        List filteredData = new ArrayList();
        Locale filterLocale = table.resolveDataLocale();
        boolean hasGlobalFilter = params.containsKey(globalFilterParam);
        String globalFilterValue = hasGlobalFilter ? params.get(globalFilterParam): null;
        GlobalFilterConstraint globalFilterConstraint = (GlobalFilterConstraint) FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.get(GLOBAL_MODE);
        ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();

        for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            table.setRowIndex(i);
            boolean localMatch = true;
            boolean globalMatch = false;

            for(FilterMeta filterMeta : filterMetadata) {
                Object filterValue = filterMeta.getFilterValue();
                UIColumn column = filterMeta.getColumn();
                MethodExpression filterFunction = column.getFilterFunction();
                ValueExpression filterByVE = filterMeta.getFilterByVE();

                if(column instanceof DynamicColumn) {
                    ((DynamicColumn) column).applyStatelessModel();
                }

                Object columnValue = filterByVE.getValue(elContext);
                FilterConstraint filterConstraint = this.getFilterConstraint(column);

                // FIX bug primefaces 5.0
                // The filter should be case insensitive 
                if(columnValue != null && filterValue!= null){
                    columnValue = columnValue.toString().toUpperCase();
                    filterValue = filterValue.toString().toUpperCase();
                }

                if(hasGlobalFilter && !globalMatch) {
                    globalMatch = globalFilterConstraint.applies(columnValue, globalFilterValue, filterLocale);
                }

                if(filterFunction != null) {
                    localMatch = (Boolean) filterFunction.invoke(elContext, new Object[]{columnValue, filterValue, filterLocale});
                }
                else if(!filterConstraint.applies(columnValue, filterValue, filterLocale)) {
                    localMatch = false;
                }

                if(!localMatch) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            boolean matches = localMatch;
            if(hasGlobalFilter) {
                matches = localMatch && globalMatch;
            }

            if(matches) {
                filteredData.add(table.getRowData());
            }
        }

        //Metadata for callback
        if(table.isPaginator()) {
            RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

            if(requestContext != null) {
                requestContext.addCallbackParam("totalRecords", filteredData.size());
            }
        }

        //save filtered data
        updateFilteredValue(context, table, filteredData);

        table.setRowIndex(-1);  //reset datamodel
    }

    public void updateFilteredValue(FacesContext context, DataTable table, List<?> value) {
        table.setSelectableDataModelWrapper(null);
        ValueExpression ve = table.getValueExpression("filteredValue");

        if(ve != null) {
            ve.setValue(context.getELContext(), value);
        }
        else {
            if(value != null) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "DataTable {0} has filtering enabled but no filteredValue model reference is defined"
                    + ", for backward compatibility falling back to page viewstate method to keep filteredValue."
                    + " It is highly suggested to use filtering with a filteredValue model reference as viewstate method is deprecated and will be removed in future."
                    , new Object[]{table.getClientId(context)});

            }

            table.setFilteredValue(value);
        }
    }

    private Map<String,Object> populateFilterParameterMap(FacesContext context, DataTable table, List<FilterMeta> filterMetadata, String globalFilterParam) {
        Map<String,String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap(); 
        Map<String,Object> filterParameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        for(FilterMeta filterMeta : filterMetadata) {
            Object filterValue = filterMeta.getFilterValue();
            UIColumn column = filterMeta.getColumn();

            if(filterValue != null && !filterValue.toString().trim().equals(Constants.EMPTY_STRING)) {
                String filterField = null;
                ValueExpression filterByVE = column.getValueExpression("filterBy");

                if(column.isDynamic()) {
                    ((DynamicColumn) column).applyStatelessModel();
                    Object filterByProperty = column.getFilterBy();
                    String field = column.getField();
                    if(field == null)
                        filterField = (filterByProperty == null) ? table.resolveDynamicField(filterByVE) : filterByProperty.toString();
                    else
                        filterField = field;
                }
                else {
                    String field = column.getField();
                    if(field == null)
                        filterField = (filterByVE == null) ? (String) column.getFilterBy(): table.resolveStaticField(filterByVE);
                    else
                        filterField = field;
                }

                filterParameterMap.put(filterField, filterValue);
            }
        }

        if(params.containsKey(globalFilterParam)) {
            filterParameterMap.put("globalFilter", params.get(globalFilterParam));
        }

        return filterParameterMap;
    }

    private List<FilterMeta> populateFilterMetaData(FacesContext context, DataTable table) {
        List<FilterMeta> filterMetadata = new ArrayList<FilterMeta>();
        String separator = String.valueOf(UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(context));
        String var = table.getVar();
        Map<String,String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

        ColumnGroup group = getColumnGroup(table, "header");
        if(group != null) {
            for(UIComponent child : group.getChildren()) {
                Row headerRow = (Row) child;

                if(headerRow.isRendered()) {
                    for(UIComponent headerRowChild : headerRow.getChildren()) {
                        Column column = (Column) headerRowChild;

                        if(column.isRendered()) {
                            ValueExpression columnFilterByVE = column.getValueExpression("filterBy");
                            Object filterByProperty = column.getFilterBy();

                            if(columnFilterByVE != null || filterByProperty != null) {
                                ValueExpression filterByVE = (columnFilterByVE != null) ? columnFilterByVE : createFilterByVE(context, var, filterByProperty);
                                UIComponent filterFacet = column.getFacet("filter");
                                Object filterValue;

                                if(filterFacet == null)
                                    filterValue = params.get(column.getClientId(context) + separator + "filter");
                                else
                                    filterValue = ((ValueHolder) filterFacet).getLocalValue();

                                filterMetadata.add(new FilterMeta(column, filterByVE, filterValue));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        else {
            for(UIColumn column : table.getColumns()) {
                ValueExpression columnFilterByVE = column.getValueExpression("filterBy");
                Object filterByProperty = column.getFilterBy();

                if (columnFilterByVE != null || filterByProperty != null) {
                    UIComponent filterFacet = column.getFacet("filter");
                    Object filterValue = null;
                    ValueExpression filterByVE = null;
                    String filterId = null;

                    if(column instanceof Column) {
                        filterByVE = (columnFilterByVE != null) ? columnFilterByVE : createFilterByVE(context, var, filterByProperty);
                        filterId = column.getClientId(context) + separator + "filter";
                    }
                    else if(column instanceof DynamicColumn) {
                        DynamicColumn dynamicColumn = (DynamicColumn) column;
                        dynamicColumn.applyStatelessModel();
                        filterByProperty = column.getFilterBy();
                        filterByVE = (filterByProperty == null) ? columnFilterByVE : createFilterByVE(context, var, filterByProperty);
                        filterId = dynamicColumn.getContainerClientId(context) + separator + "filter";
                        dynamicColumn.cleanStatelessModel();
                    }

                    if(filterFacet == null)
                        filterValue = params.get(filterId);
                    else
                        filterValue = ((ValueHolder) filterFacet).getLocalValue();

                    filterMetadata.add(new FilterMeta(column, filterByVE, filterValue));
                }
            }
        }

      return filterMetadata;
   }

   private ColumnGroup getColumnGroup(DataTable table, String target) {
        for(UIComponent child : table.getChildren()) {
            if(child instanceof ColumnGroup) {
                ColumnGroup colGroup = (ColumnGroup) child;
                String type = colGroup.getType();

                if(type != null && type.equals(target)) {
                    return colGroup;
                }

            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public FilterConstraint getFilterConstraint(UIColumn column) {
        String filterMatchMode = column.getFilterMatchMode();
        FilterConstraint filterConstraint  = FILTER_CONSTRAINTS.get(filterMatchMode);

        if(filterConstraint == null) { 
            throw new FacesException("Illegal filter match mode:" + filterMatchMode);
        }

        return filterConstraint;
    }

    private ValueExpression createFilterByVE(FacesContext context, String var, Object filterBy) {
        ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
        return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(elContext, "#{" + var + "." + filterBy + "}", Object.class);
    }

    private class FilterMeta {

        private UIColumn column;
        private ValueExpression filterByVE;
        private Object filterValue;

        public FilterMeta(UIColumn column, ValueExpression filterByVE, Object filterValue) {
            this.column = column;
            this.filterByVE = filterByVE;
            this.filterValue = filterValue;
        }

        public UIColumn getColumn() {
            return column;
        }

        public ValueExpression getFilterByVE() {
            return filterByVE;
        }

        public Object getFilterValue() {
            return filterValue;
        }        

    }
}
```

Comment: reasonable approach for eager tables

Answer (score 1):

I took a little more simplistic approach to get past this in my situation.

In my XHTML:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{car.nameLowercase}" sortBy="#{car.name}" 
        filterMatchMode="contains">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.name}"/>
</p:column>
```

In my car bean I simply add a getter:

```
public String getNameLowerCase() {
   if (name == null) {
      return null;
   }
   return name.toLowerCase();
}
```

This seems to work for my purposes. Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on the Lazy.xhtml, I fixied it by go to the LazyCarDataModel.java, on load method, change

```
if(filterValue==null || 
    fieldvalue.startswith(filtervalue.toString()))
```

to

```
if(filterValue==null ||
    fieldvalue.startswith(filtervalue.toString().toLowerCase() ||
    fieldvalue.startswith(filtervalue.toString().toUpperCase()) )
```